# Delay FIN-ACK sent on linux

Tags: tcp, curl

For a project I need to delay the FIN-ACK sent in an SSL connection on Linux. Is there any way to do this? I can send an https request by using `curl https://www.google.com`, but how do I modify the TCP stack so that the final FIN-ACK sent is delayed?

Comment: Well, if you are writing your own code, you could use the LINGER option in setsockopt

Comment: @fpmurphy1 linger doesn't delay *sending* anything; it waits during close() if necessary to *receive* ACKs (at least for in-flight data and I think but am not positive for ACK to FIN).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with kernel build-in [netem](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem#Delay_distribution) you could delay the traffic

see this discussion: [Network tools that simulate slow network connection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1094797/4501350)

Comment: Thank you for the help, I finally ended up using usleep before closing the socket so that FIN-ACK sent is delayed, but netem was also very useful. Thanks again !